# Saving Unicode text to MS Access from VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, unicode

Hey i am making a project on VB.NET in which my text boxes have FONT property set to "TERAFONT-VARUN, 12pt " which is for GUJARATI language.
Now i want to save the data of text box into my MS ACCESS  data base.

I also want to retrieve that data for other purpose.

Can you please tell me what to do?

Comment: What problem are you having? Does the text come back mangled? What version of MS Access are you using?

Comment: hey thx for the comment but i eventual solve the problem....i type cast my text box field's data to STRING..and db is accounting string....so no need to convert it into uncod...and whn i print the data back to the form..text box's font property convert string into GUJARATI...

again thx for commet..

Answer (score 1):

.Net uses Unicode and you should be able to safely save Unicode strings to Access without problems.
Note that the font you are using doesn't matter here, it's only important for *displaying* Unicode to the user. It has nothing to do with the database.

To save data to Access from .Net, you can have a look at these resources:

- [How do you insert new entries into an Access db table through an ASP.net website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575821/how-do-you-insert-new-entries-into-an-access-db-table-through-an-asp-net-website)
- [Introduction to some basic classes of ADO.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/adodotnet.aspx) on CodeProject.

This should get you started on using Access databases from your .Net programs.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that unicode text inserting to or from the database is not the issue neither formating the unicode. The problem to notice is that while inserting, unicode may contain coded value (") which indirectly terminates the string at that point only. and the rest of the string is considered as code, which is considered to be stack overflow by the program at the runtime.